# Выражение "Остаться с носом"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "Остаться с носом"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае слово "нос" означает не часть лица, а происходит от слова "нести". В старину подношение, которое приносил приходящий свататься к девушке жених, тоже называли "нос". Таким образом, выражение "остаться с носом" означается, что у человека не приняли его подарок.